# EXCEL Formula or VBA To Extract Data Based on Another Cell's Data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following worksheet #1 (simplified for the question) of person and age:

```
Person    Age
Bob       40
Brett     35
Brian     38
```

I would like to setup another worksheet where I have the following:

```
Person    Age
Spot #1  FORMULA
```

The user will enter a name in Spot #1 and I want a formula/code in the cell titled FORMULA where the formula/VBA code will look at the table in worksheet #1 and pull in the appropriate age based on the person entered in .

What formula can I use to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052093351033.aspx) function.  This example below assumes that your data table is in Sheet1!A1:B4.  Although I would recommend that you make your data table a [Named Range](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052015361033.aspx?pid=CH010036991033) and reference it using VLOOKUP(A2, MyDataTable, 2)

```
Person    Age
Spot #1   =VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A1:B4, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

try the vLookup function